# error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object' Note! Check The Picture Contains Error Please

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

[error Photo >Check it Please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Zcp.jpg)[> import 'package:buy_it/constants.dart'; import

> 'package:buy_it/models/product.dart'; import
> 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'; import
> 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import
> 'package:buy_it/services/store.dart'; import
> 'package:buy_it/constants.dart'; class EditProduct extends
> StatefulWidget {   static String id = 'EditProduct';
>
> @override   _EditProductState createState() => _EditProductState();
> }
>
> class _EditProductState extends State {   final
> _store=Store();   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
> return Scaffold(
> body: StreamBuilder(
> stream: _store.loadProducts(),
> builder: (context ,snapshot)
> {
> if(snapshot.hasData){
> List products = [];
> for (var doc in snapshot.data.docs) {
> var data = doc.data();
> products.add(Product(
> pPrice: data[kProductPrice],
> pName: data[kProductName],
> pDescreption: data[kProductDescreption],
> pCategory: data[kProductCategory],
> pLocation: data[kProductLocation]));
> }
> return ListView.builder(itemBuilder:
> (context ,index) => Text(products[index].pName),
> itemCount: products.length,
> );
> }else
> {
> return Center(child: Text('Loading ....'));
> }
> },
> ),
> );   }
>
> }][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDGTQ.jpg)

Comment: Try `var data = doc.data` not `doc.data()`. If you're using firestore.

Comment: Still Error , thank you